# The exception related to FieldRenderer in Sitecore 8

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, sitecore8

Today I'm writing a custom method that its inheritance :

> RenderingModel

My HomeModel have only one field.

```
public HtmlString Title { get; set; }
```

When I rendering this field as below

```
var home = new HomeModel();
home.Title = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(this.Item, "Title"));
```

The problem is that I getting the exception.

```
Could not find method: Process. Pipeline: /sitecore[database="SqlServer" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"]/pipelines/renderField/processor[type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.SetParameters, Sitecore.Kernel"]
```

Another approach I write a method inherit IRenderingModel then call

```
public void Initialize(Rendering rendering) { }
```

But this exception still occurs. Everyone have idea for this ?

Same this problem :
https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/7/t/1392

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just write:

`home.Title = new HtmlString(this.Item["Title"]);`

Or

`this.Item.Fields["Title"].Value`

Assuming that `Item` is of `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` type and that `FieldRenderer.Render` is the issue.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: - Thanks for your answer, purpose I used to FieldRenderer.Render is to use Experience Editor, the way of you also take the result but not in my case.
- Yes, Item is of Sitecore.Data.Items.Item

Comment: What about using: @Html.Sitecore().Field(Item, "Title") directly in your cshtml file, is there a reason why you can't use that?